# SQL not bringing back integer value - Classic ASP

Tags: sql, asp-classic

I have a site that I'm maintaining in classic ASP. Very straight forward sql statement, bringing back all the values except Remote. The value in the database for this particular person is 1, but value is coming back empty. Any ideas what could be causing for the value not to come through? The field in database defined as an integer that accepts NULL value as well.

Here is the SQL statement:

```
strSQL = "SELECT PersonID, HRID, EligibleSponsor, FirstName, LastName, Title, Role, Cell, EntityID, Email,"
strSQL = strSQL & " WorkgroupID, Location, Extension, PhoneNumber, Display, DisplayPicture, LocationID, SupervisorID,"
strSQL = strSQL & " DID, HireDate, BirthDate, AboutMe, Type, Site, Remote, del, CostCenterID"
strSQL = strSQL & " FROM Person WHERE PersonID=" & Request("PersonID")
```

This is the value that's coming back empty, when it should be 1.

```
iRemote = rs("Remote")
```

Everything else is coming back correctly, except this one field.

I also have similar SQL statement on another page on the same site and that value is coming through correctly, but not for this page. I've compared the pages but can't find anything that was differently to get the value.

Answer (score 2):

First, your code is wide open for SQL Injection attack. I know it's not related to your problem but it's just horribly bad to have such code, since anyone can take control over your database and possibly whole web server.

Second, some field names might be reserved words, including "Remote". This might explain the problem.

Third, depends how you're using `iRemote` might cause the problem since `rs("Remote")` return a complex object, not an integer.

Following is optimized version of your code, that is both protected against SQL Injection attacks  and should return proper values:

```vbs
strSQL = "SELECT PersonID, HRID, EligibleSponsor, FirstName, LastName, [Title], [Role], [Cell], EntityID, [Email],"
strSQL = strSQL & " WorkgroupID, [Location], [Extension], PhoneNumber, [Display], DisplayPicture, LocationID, SupervisorID,"
strSQL = strSQL & " [DID], HireDate, BirthDate, AboutMe, [Type], [Site], [Remote], [del], CostCenterID"
strSQL = strSQL & " FROM Person WHERE PersonID=?"
set objCommand = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command") 
objCommand.ActiveConnection = objConnection 
objCommand.CommandText = strSQL
objCommand.Parameters(0).value = Request("PersonID")
Set rs = objCommand.Execute()
''...
iRemote = CLng(rs.Fields("Remote").Value)
```